# How do I add a variable that counts how many objects there are in a string? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

So, I could have a code that says something like

```
var J = [12 , 26 , 34 , 93 , 50];
```

but is there a code that allows me to have a variable that counts how many numbers there are? Also, is there a code that allows me to arrange them in ascending and descending order? 
Like in the previous example there are 5 numbers, so the code could go something like

```
var K = 5;
```

or something like that?
Thank you!

Comment: `.length` and [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Did you search on Google before coming here?

Comment: This is the epitome of "lacks research effort"

Comment: @mplungjan not the best duplicate... might as well just downvote and close as 'too broad' or something then delete?

Comment: @AndrewLi shame we're still waiting on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back

Comment: @AndrewLi - I cannot hammer close too broad ;)

Comment: Someone close as "Lacks any research effort"

Comment: @mplungjan A tragedy. If only high rep users got better privileges to remove bad posts more easily so the site wouldn't be bombarded with such posts. I really wish the 'lacks minimal understanding' CV reason comes back.

Comment: @Karis, Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] - we really like questions to have a minimum of research effort put into them - for example visit the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) documentation to see ALL you can do with an array

Comment: flagging this, as this question lacks basic research effort...

Answer (score -1):

```
var J = [12 , 26 , 34 , 93 , 50, '50'];

var newArr = J.filter((i) => typeof (i) === 'number');
console.log(newArr.length); // 5
```

for sorting, use sort function on `newArr`